# Is it bad typesetting practice to split boxes over two pages?

Tags: tcolorbox, page-breaking, layout

I can't decide what I prefer - having empty space at the end of a page or a split box.

For example:

[image]

Should I be aiming to make sure the page is full with no need to break boxes? Like, I can add more text I probably don't need further up the page so that the last box starts on a new page, is this something people do for aesthetics?

Or should I be happy enough with a break like this? Or the empty space?

[image]

Comment: If a box is really long and solid text, splitting it in the middle isn't objectionable.  But the boxes you show aren't like that, and I find them questionable.  I'd try to figure out a way to fill the pages so those breaks could be avoided.  (Personal opinion.  YMMV.)

Comment: Both options are bad to rage, but there are a third option (at least to me,  usually better):  make the boxes floating objects (`floatplacement` option in a tcolorbox, or just a `figure` environment without caption for any type of non floating box).  This will not help with boxes longer than une page,  but the first to consider if is a good idea make so long  boxes   A small box with is perfect to highlight some content from the long and boring main text. A broken long box is just more boring text  harder to read because the gray background.

Comment: A good option is not to use the framed boxes at all. They do not add much value.

Comment: @mickep sure they do. These are notes for students which will be lengthy and having the main content standing out is of great benefit when they come to revise.